# How can i setup my discord bot automatically?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot but I want when someone add my bot to their server they dont need to write !setup. How I can do it automatically ?

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
 if (message.content === '!setup') {
    await message.guild.commands
      .set(client.commands)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Client#guildCreate` event

For instance:

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    // What to do when the bot is invited
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under client in the discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) there is an event called guildCreate which is emitted when the client joins a guild. If you listen for this event and run your setup code when it is emitted this might be what your after.

```
const { Client, Intents} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    //Your setup code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one server that you wan to add the bot to, you can do it manually. Just follow these steps:

Go into discord developer portal > click on your bot > Oauth2 > URl Generator > click bot and any other scope you might need > choose your perms > copy and past the link into your browser and you should be done!

To do this however, you must have manage server perms in that server

Comment: You don't need admin for anything in a server, except permission overwrite override. You just need Manage Server permission to invite a bot